# <div> in navbar not aligning properly

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, razor

I'm using the basic bootstrap css with nothing altered, and I have the following html in a Razor View in ASP.NET MVC:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                <!--<span class="icon-bar"></span>-->
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            @Html.ActionLink("Application name", "Index", "Home", new { area = "" }, new { @class = "navbar-brand" })
        </div>
        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                @if (ViewBag.WidgetPages != null)
                {
                    foreach (WidgetPage page in ViewBag.WidgetPages)
                    {                            
                        <li class="navbar-collapse"><div>
                            <a href="@Url.Action("Index", "WidgetPage")" class="navbar-link">@page.Title  </a>
                            <a href="@Url.Action("Edit", "WidgetPage", new { id = page.Id })" class="navbar-link"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil" role="button"></span></a>
                            <a href="@Url.Action("Delete", "WidgetPage", new { id = page.Id })" class="navbar-link"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" role="button"></span></a>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                    }
                }
                <li><a href="@Url.Action("Create", "WidgetPage")">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
            @Html.Partial("_LoginPartial")
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

All my navigation links are working just as they should - however, the alignment of the navigation bar is off from what I expect and want. What I'm ending up with is http://puu.sh/kN0NJ/ea996c060b.png, and what I'm hoping to get is simply all of the items aligned on the same line.

Update: I have the following CSS in my content folder:

```
.navbar.navbar-edit .navbar-nav li.edited .edit-link a {
  color: #fff;
}
.navbar.navbar-edit .navbar-nav li.edited .edit-link a:hover {
  color: #ccc;
}
  .navbar.navbar-edit .navbar-nav li.edited a {
      display: inline-block;
      position: relative;
      padding-right: 4px;
      padding-left: 4px;
  }
  .navbar.navbar-edit .navbar-nav .edit-link{
      padding-left: 4px;
      padding-right: 4px;
  }
  @media (max-width: 767px){
      .navbar.navbar-edit .navbar-nav li.edited a{
          padding-left: 15px;
      }
  }
```

with the following Razor View code:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-edit navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                    <!--<span class="icon-bar"></span>-->
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                @Html.ActionLink("Application name", "Index", "Home", new { area = "" }, new { @class = "navbar-brand" })
            </div>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    @if (ViewBag.WidgetPages != null)
                    {
                        foreach (WidgetPage page in ViewBag.WidgetPages)
                        {
                            <li class="edited">
                                <a href="@Url.Action("Index","WidgetPage",new { id = @page.Id })" class="navbar-link">@page.Title</a>
                                <span class="edit-link"><a href="@Url.Action("Edit", "WidgetPage", new { id = @page.Id })" class="navbar-link">
                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil" role="button"></span></a></span>
                                <span class="edit-link">
                                    <a href="@Url.Action("Delete", "WidgetPage", new { id = @page.Id })" class="navbar-link">
                                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" role="button"></span>
                                    </a>
                                </span>
                            </li>
                        }
                    }
                    <li>
                        <a href="@Url.Action("Create", "WidgetPage")">
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>

                @Html.Partial("_LoginPartial")
        </div>
    </nav>
```

but I'm still ending up with the stacked buttons. I'm really at a loss here for what is happening.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your HTML structure is off (unless you're trying to do something outside of the defaults or maybe a dropdown?). [Docs](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar)

You have `navbar-collapse` twice and multiple `href's` inside one `li` element.

**UPDATE:**

You can add a custom class to the list items with Icons inside them to adjust the padding and then use media queries to have them remain inline on mobile viewports.

See updated example.

```css
/**BELOW NOT REQUIRED, ONLY FOR CONTEXT**/

.navbar.navbar-custom li.edit span {
  color: #eee;
}
.navbar.navbar-custom li.edit span:hover {
  color: #ccc;
}
/**ABOVE NOT REQUIRED, ONLY FOR CONTEXT**/

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .navbar.navbar-custom li.edit a {
    padding-left: 4px;
    padding-right: 4px;
  }
}
@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .navbar.navbar-custom li.edit {
    display: table-cell;
  }
  .navbar.navbar-custom li.edit a {
    padding-right: 4px;
  }
}
/**UPDATED NAVBAR RULES - LOOP**/

/**BELOW NOT REQUIRED, ONLY FOR CONTEXT**/

.navbar.navbar-edit .navbar-nav li.edited .edit-link a {
  color: #fff;
}
.navbar.navbar-edit .navbar-nav li.edited .edit-link a:hover {
  color: #ccc;
}
/**ABOVE NOT REQUIRED, ONLY FOR CONTEXT**/

.navbar.navbar-edit .navbar-nav li.edited a {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 4px;
  padding-right: 4px;
}
.navbar.navbar-edit .navbar-nav .edit-link {
  padding-left: 4px;
  padding-right: 4px;
}
@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .navbar.navbar-edit .navbar-nav li.edited a {
    padding-left: 15px;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-custom">
  <div class="container">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-1" aria-expanded="false"> <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>

      </button>
    </div>
    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="edit"><a href="@Url.Action(" Index ", "WidgetPage ")" class="navbar-link">This is a Title  </a>

        </li>
        <li class="edit"><a href="@Url.Action(" Edit ", "WidgetPage ", new { id = page.Id })" class="navbar-link"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil" role="button"></span></a>

        </li>
        <li class="edit"><a href="@Url.Action(" Delete ", "WidgetPage ", new { id = page.Id })" class="navbar-link"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" role="button"></span></a>

        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="@Url.Action(" Create ", "WidgetPage ")">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>
          </a>

        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div>
  <!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
<hr>
<div class="alert alert-info">
  <h3>Updated NAVBAR</h3>
</div>
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-edit">
  <div class="container">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-2" aria-expanded="false"> <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>

      </button>
    </div>
    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-2">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="edited"><a href="#" class="navbar-link">This is a Title  </a>
          <span class="edit-link"><a href="#" class="navbar-link"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil" role="button"> </span>

          </a>
          </span> <span class="edit-link"><a href="#" class="navbar-link"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" role="button"></span>

          </a>
          </span>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span> 
          </a>

        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div>
  <!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
```

Comment: Ah, pointing out the nested navbar-collapse is spot-on. I missed that. However, I am trying to have the pencil and remove glyphicons (and their relevant actions) very close to the page title, as they are intended as edit/remove for each page title. Using each as a separate `li` makes the spacing uniform across the entire bar which is not quite what I'm looking for. Edit: Thanks for the great example on how to get html code running in a stack overflow discussion - I'll make sure to do that in the future.

Comment: That looks great. I didn't save the first edit - would you mind briefly explaining what changes you made? I'm experienced with C#, but mostly new to Razor, html and css, so there's a whole lot to learn. Thank you!

Comment: If you want to see the difference in structure just head to the Docs and compare yours from the navbar-nav class down. The only changes I've made from the default structure is adding a custom class called "edit" to the links that should be closer together (and one class to the navbar so the core CSS isn't directly changed). It's  a matter of adjusting the padding on each side for the viewport above 768px (thats where the navigation changes to mobile), then once the navigation is under 768px I'm applying a display property to keep the links in a row while also adjusting the padding for mobile.

Comment: Ah. The problem with this is that looping through to add more than one page ends up with the pages and their buttons all mushed together. Would it make sense to have "edit-left", edit-center" and "edit right" class with left-padding, both-side-padding, and right-padding (respectively) so that the buttons of one page can be grouped together but each group is discrete?

Comment: Sounds like you're on the right track but I did put an additional update in the answer Snippet (second navbar) that may help or be closer to what you had originally set out for.

Comment: That seems a lot more elegant than what I had in mind - and extendable to adding more buttons (I shouldn't need to but who knows) in the future without having to make a ton of changes. Thank you!

Comment: Ah, drat. Sorry to have this discussion in comments - but I don't have enough rep to chat. I've made the changes you did, and I initially thought they would work, but I'm still ending up with http://puu.sh/kNDcP/8bfdb32f11.png and the display shows as "block" for those li elements in my browser html explorer. I'm truly baffled, as the classes seem to be applied correctly.

Comment: The first thing that comes to mind is if you're using the exact CSS from the answer, did you apply this class (navbar-edit) to your navbar?

Comment: I made an update to my original post with the current state of my code and the results of running said code.

Comment: Ah. Must be on my end. I'll do some snooping and figure it out! Thanks for all your help.

Comment: Maybe try this refactored version (it's just pasted into jsfiddle so you can copy it) > [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vanburen/zyn18oek/)